# Повторный ввод данных в форму обратной связи вызывает ошибку

Tags: javascript, php, html

Всем привет, помогите разобраться пожалуйста, есть форма обратной связи, при первом ее использовании все работает отлично, отправка, проверки и т.д. После отправки открывается модальное окно с сообщением об ошибке/отправке, и так же форма очищается, но если сайт не перезагружать, то при повторном вводе код выбивает ошибку то что переменная не идентифицирована.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      // Форма обратной связи................................./

      var regVr22 = "<div id='obr'><img style='margin-bottom:-4px;' src='../images/load.gif' alt='Отправка...' width='16' height='16'><span style='font: 14px Verdana; color:#fff; margin-left:6px; top: 20px; font-weight: bold;'>Сообщение обрабатывается...</span></div><br />";

      $("#send_call").click(function() {
        $("#loadBar1").html(regVr22).show();
        var posName = $("#posName1").val();
        var posEmail = $("#posEmail1").val();
        var posTel = $("#posTel1").val();
        var posText = $("#posText1").val();
        var type = $("#type1").val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://тут мой сайт/send.php",
          data: {
            "posName": posName,
            "posEmail": posEmail,
            "posTel": posTel,
            "posText": posText,
            "type": type
          },
          cache: false,
          success: function(response) {
            var messageResp = "<p style='font-family:Verdana; font-size:14px; font-weight: bold;color:green; border:1px solid #00CC00; padding:5px; margin:20px; border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px; background-color:#fff;'>Спасибо, <strong>";
            var resultStat = "!</strong> Ваш заказ принят в обработку. В ближайшее время наш менеджер свяжется с Вами для подтверждения заказа.</p>";
            var oll = (messageResp + posName + resultStat);
            if (response == 1) {
              $("#loadBar1").html(oll).fadeIn(3000);
              $("#posName1").val('');
              $("#posEmail1").val('');
              $("#posTel1").val('');
              $("#posText1").val('');
              $("#type1").val('');
              //    yaCounter31997576.reachGoal('TARGET'); return true; 
            } else {
              $("#loadBar1").html(response).fadeIn(3000);
            }
          }
        });
        return false;
      });
```

```html
<div class="col-md-7 mb-5 site-animate">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="control-label">Имя:<span class="required_field_comment_star">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="posName1" placeholder="Введите имя">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="tel" class="control-label">Телефон:<span class="required_field_comment_star">*</span></label>
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="posTel1" placeholder="Введите телефон">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="control-label">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="posEmail1" placeholder="Введите Email">
    </div>
    <input value="zvon" id="type1" type="hidden" />
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message" class="control-label">Сообщение:</label>
      <textarea name="message" id="posText1" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите сообщение"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg show_popup" value="Send Message" rel="form2" href="#" type="submit" id="send_call">Заказать звонок</button>
    </div>
    <p class="required_field_comment">Поля отмеченные <span class="required_field_comment_star">*</span> обязательны к заполнению!</p>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7 mb-5">
  <div class="form2">
    <a class="close" href="#">Close</a>
    <div align="center" id='loadBar1'></div>
    <form action="#" method="post" id="cForm2">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
<< ? php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
//**********************************************
if (empty($_POST['js'])) {

  $log = '';
  $error = "no"; //флаг наличия ошибки

  $posName = addslashes($_POST['posName']);
  $posName = htmlspecialchars($posName);
  $posName = stripslashes($posName);
  $posName = trim($posName);

  $posTel = addslashes($_POST['posTel']);
  $posTel = htmlspecialchars($posTel);
  $posTel = stripslashes($posTel);
  $posTel = trim($posTel);

  $posEmail = addslashes($_POST['posEmail']);
  $posEmail = htmlspecialchars($posEmail);
  $posEmail = stripslashes($posEmail);
  $posEmail = trim($posEmail);

  $posText = addslashes($_POST['posText']);
  $posText = htmlspecialchars($posText);
  $posText = stripslashes($posText);
  $posText = trim($posText);

  $type = addslashes($_POST['type']);
  $type = htmlspecialchars($type);
  $type = stripslashes($type);
  $type = trim($type);

  //Проверка правильность имени    
  if ($posName == '') {
    $log. = "<li>Заполните поле \"Ваше имя\"!</li>";
    $error = "yes";
  }

  //Проверка телефона
  $posTelCheck = $posTel;
  if (strlen($posTelCheck) > 0) {
    if (preg_match("/^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$/", $posTelCheck)) {} else {
      $log. = "<li>Введен неверный номер телефона</li>";
      $error = "yes";
    }
  } else {
    $log. = "<li>Пожалуйста, введите Ваш телефон!</li>";
    $error = "yes";
  }

  //Проверка email адреса
  //if($posEmail == '')
  //                {
  //    $log .= "<li>Пожалуйста, введите Ваш Email!</li>";
  //    $error = "yes";
  //}
  $posEmailCheck = $posEmail;
  if (strlen($posEmailCheck) > 0) {
    if (preg_match("/^([a-z0-9_-]+\.)*[a-z0-9_-]+@[a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}$/", $posEmailCheck)) {} else {
      $log. = "<li>Email введен неверно</li>";
      $error = "yes";
    }
  }

  //Проверка наличия введенного текста комментария
  //Проверка длины текста комментария
  if (strlen($posText) > 2000) {
    $log. = "<li>Слишком длинное сообщение (более 2000 символов) в тексте записи!</li>";
    $error = "yes";
  }
  //Проверка на наличие длинных слов
  $mas = preg_split("/[\s]+/", $posText);
  foreach($mas as $index => $val) {
    if (strlen($val) > 60) {
      $log. = "<li>Слишком длинные слова (более 60 символов) в тексте записи!</li>";
      $error = "yes";
      break;
    }
  }
  sleep(2);

  //Если нет ошибок отправляем email  
  if ($error == "no") {
    $totype = "Заказ";
    if ($type == "zakaz") $totype = "Заказал(а) товар";
    if ($type == "kons") $totype = "Заказал(а) консультацию по товару";
    if ($type == "zvon") $totype = "Заказал(а) обратный звонок";
    //Отправка письма админу о новом комментарии
    $to = "мояпочта@mail.ru"; //Ваш e-mail адрес
    if ($type == "zvon") {
      $mes = "Имя:  $posName \n\nТелефон:  $posTelCheck \n\nСообщение: $posText  \n\nEmail: $posEmailCheck \n\nТип обращения: $totype \n\n";
    } else if ($type == "kons") {
      $mes = "Имя $posName \n\nТелефон $posTelCheck \n\n $totype\n\n";
    } else if ($type == "zakaz") {
      $mes = "Человек по имени $posName отправил Вам сообщение \n\nТелефон $posTel \n\n $totype\n\n";
    }


    $from = 'posEmail';
    $sub = '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode('Новое сообщение с Вашего сайта').
    '?=';
    $headers = 'From: '.$from.
    '
    ';
    $headers. = 'MIME-Version: 1.0
    ';
    $headers. = 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
    ';
    mail($to, $sub, $mes, $headers);
    echo "1"; //Всё Ok!
  } else //если ошибки есть
  {
    echo "<br /><ul style='list-style: none; font: 14px Verdana; color:#000;font-weight: bold; border:1px solid #c00; border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px; background-color:#fff; padding:5px; margin:5px 10px;'>".$log.
    "</ul><br />"; //Нельзя отправлять пустые сообщения

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input value="zvon" id="type1" type="hidden" />
                                     ^^^^^^
```

Вы перестарались с очищением инпутов:

```
//$("#type1").val('');
```